# Large index match with multiple criteria, duplicate values error

Tags: microsoft-excel, duplicate

I'm trying to return values based upon multiple criteria. I've tried everything I can think of to get this working but I must be missing something!

The formula I have which works so far is:

```
 {=INDEX(Table1[Session],MATCH(1,($G24=Table1[FTD +/-])*(D6=Table1[Weeknum])*(D7=Table1[Yearnum]),0))}
```

But I need it to recognise duplicates and bring the next 'Session' when there is a match.

[image]

So in the example above it shouldn't say "Cardiff" twice - it should pull the next score from `Table1[FTD +/-]` with `-7`

See database here: https://we.tl/t-4sFsUnr7VB

Comment: This is going to be hard for people to respond to without knowing what the spreadsheet looks like and what those named ranges apply to.  Please add a screenshot and provide some more context.  Nobody here is familiar with what you're trying to do, other than this description of how it isn't working.

Comment: Even though spreadsheet doesn't completely make sense to me (you seem to be pre-populating with "+/-" and then looking up "session") I believe I see problem.  The Match function will always pull up the first instance of what is being matched.  Someone else may have a way of working around this.  Depending on what you are trying to do, pivot table might be much simpler approach.

Comment: Hello thanks for getting back. Apologies for the lack of info on my part. I'm struggling to see where I can upload it now so I've created a downloadable link for an example file: https://we.tl/t-4sFsUnr7VB

Comment: @AndrewSHarris2019,, I've one confusion if data has 3 Cerdiff and 1st has -7, 2nd -10 & 3rd Cardiff has -1,, in that case which one you want to extract (is there any preference in regard of occurrence for duplicates)!!